# Directly access the VGA pins on linux

Tags: linux, vga

My motherboard has a VGA output port, just like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector#/media/File:SVGA_port.jpg).

Let's say I want to directly access the state of each of the pins on this connector, so that I could control some electronic device, is there any way I can do this?

I'm on Linux, and my first thought was to have a look in `/sys/class/`, since I know from there I can control certain LEDs on my keyboard, and such. Interestingly, I found a folder called `gpio`, but I can't any information about how to use that (since I'm not on a raspberry Pi, or anything, I don't have GPIO pins to my knowledge.)

So, *is* there any way to control the state of individual VGA pins?

Comment: VGA is not a GPIO port. It’s not even a digital output.

Comment: @DanielB I know it's not a GPIO port.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61290/usb-to-gpio-module

Comment: @xenoid Thanks! Those answers look good, but if I need to use something like that I'll just try to make the adapter myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly control the state of exactly two pins, namely the clock and data pins for the I2C bus used for EDID. See [pinout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector).

However, unless you use an electronic device which itself is controlled by I2C (there are plenty, for example I2C expanders like the MCP23008 or MCP23017, which give you 8 resp. 16 signals you can then control directly via the I2C bus), you'll have to modify your existing video driver to give you an API where you can directly set the state.

You can indirectly control the red, green, blue and the two sync pins in a repeating, time-dependent way, by programming your VGA controller with the timing and writing bit patterns in the frame buffer. This may or may not be useful, depending on what you want to do with it.